# I was coding a Website in html and css. The code worked, except the css didn't, why?

Tags: html, css

I was making a website in which a link is clicked. It then goes to a new website. I was coding that Website in html and css. The code worked, except the css didn't, why? Here is my code for the link part.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/Osprey/Documents/Wolves Web Html/Notepad++/Guess_style.css">
    <title>Guess</title>

 </head>

 <header class="guess_the_card">
        <h1>Guess</h1>
        <p>What's that card?</p>
</header>

<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Osprey/Documents/Wolves%20Web%20Html/Notepad++/card_games.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>

<main>
        <section>
            <header>

                <h2>Guess</h2>
            </header>

            <article>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQx0pwiW_DP9LMCGohHDhDPzQ7E80Dt8Ea08m4Adpe3tGaYqU8R" alt="question mark" height="350" width="400">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_FodQOfRQnVYUULNy-9YGh3Wm-naW10nEk0mCv3qi_rW7c4o7Mw"alt="card" height="350" width="400">
                <h3>How To Play: </h3>
                <h4>Players: </h4>
                <p>2<br><br></p>
                <h4>Objective: </h4>
                <p>Be the first to guess the other player's card.<br><br></p>
                <h4>THE DEAL</h4>
                <p>The deal is extremely simple. It's just two easy steps! First you get a deck
                Then each player picks one card. The deal is done. See, I told you it's simple.<br><br></p>
                <h4>THE PLAY</h4>
                <p>After the deal, the youngest player asks a question to the other player. This question can be like is your card a royal?
                Or is your card lower then five? The other player answers the question and then asks a similar question. Once a player thinks 
                he or she has eough information to guess, they guess the other player's card. For example, is your card a king?(If answer was 
                yes then during next turn player responds by asking) Is your card a king of diamonds? (if not, then players keeps guessing turn 
                by turn until one player gets it right. That player then wins.)</p>

            </article>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: what mean by not working, ur css is pointing to the local file which not able to access

Comment: I notice from your profile that you are Middle School. I started learning HTML in middle school many years ago too. Please don't be discouraged if your post is downvoted. This question has been asked many times before here, and there can be a steep learning curve of Stack Overflow culture... but I implore you to stick with it

Comment: Oh it worked now. Guess the css was just coded wrong. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 1):

In linking your css, change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Osprey\Documents\"Wolves Web Html"\Notepad++\Guess_style.css">
```

instead of slash, use backslash and if you still want to use space in your folder, please put quote or make your folder without space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/Osprey/Documents/Wolves Web Html/Notepad++/Guess_style.css">
```

A couple of things.

First, never use an absolute link to a css file that is on your c: drive.

Second: You have spaces in your Website Folder.

```
Wolves Web Html
```

Rename your folder something like wolveswebhtml, or wolves-web-html, or wolves_web_html.

Third: How come your linking to a stylesheet inside of notepad++? 
I don't think i've personally have ever seen that. I think you should read up more on beginning web development and how to structure your folders and using relative linking for your css files.

Fourth: I suggest creating a brand new folder somewhere, it looks like you like to work in your documents folder.

Name the folder WolvesWebHtml

Use this folder for all your files. 
Example. Inside the folder you might have>

```
index.html
css/ < folder
js/ < folder
images/ < folder

etc....etc..
```

Place your stylesheet in the css folder, and then using relative linking, you can link to your stylesheet by using.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Guess_style.css">
```

Will make life a lot easier.

You don't need to use text=text/css anymore when linking to css files.

I suggest also that you ditch notepad++ and use a better free editor such as brackets. It's free, open-source, and runs on every operating system. Very easy to learn.

I suggest you read more on the basics of setting up a website, html, and css. Many tutorials out there. Best of luck!

Comment: I made the new file and did exactly as you said but it still didn't work, do you think my css code is wrong?

Comment: what does your folder structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to web development, too. You might get some flack for the simpleness of your question, but to a beginner, things can be confusing.

The url referenced in your style tag is to a file locally on your computer `C:/Users/Osprey/Documents/Wolves Web Html/Notepad++/Guess_style.css` notice that this is different that what you might see at on a website on the internet `http://example.com/file.css`. Your browser likely doesn't know how to find `Guess_style.css` because it doesn't understand what `C:/...` means.

While prefixing the link with `file:///` may work, it can often be blocked by browsers for security reasons. The best solution to this problem is to reference the file locally to where it is being called `./Guess_style.css` and to use actual server software on your computer to serve and access the website you're developing.

Your computer may already have some software like that installed, such as Apache, or IIS. If you would like a very simple solution, I would recommend using a tool called [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm?utm_source=house&utm_medium=homepage&utm_campaign=free%20orgs&utm_term=Install%20npm) and installing a very simple server called [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). This would allow you to serve the files from your computer as if they were from an actual web server and will greatly help in your learning. Good luck!